# How to bring data from the BDD for a web page with HTML + CSS + JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web, charts

I have a website designed with html, css and I am using charts with JavaScript to represent the database results. My question is, what is the best way to extract data and inject it into the graphics made ​​with JavaScript?

I have worked with php before, but I have understood that the JS execute after loading the whole page and php execute before the page loads, so i cant use both at the "same time".

I thought about creating invisible tables and put data there (would be easy with php when loading the view) and, with the JS load those results to the charts (but it sounds highly inefficient).

I also though about using AJAX with Php in order to extract the data dinamically from server and loading it in my charts (would be that OK?).

You are the experts. So, what do you suggest?

Comment: Loading data using ajax call to PHP is the best and possibly only way for you. you need to have PHP running on server.

Comment: And if I'm willing to learn a new language, wich one would be the best? or this is it? Thx